# Russian time zone changes

Tags: timezone

As many of you know, Russia has *eleven* time zones, and has (or will) cut two of them. It is possible that they may end daylight savings time altogether.

Does anyone know if they *have* cut two time zones, and if daylight savings is now a thing of the past? If so, does daylight savings end in all time zones, or just some?

I maintain some software that may need to be patched and can't find two news sites that agree on if they have, or have not implemented these changes.

My biggest concern is daylight savings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia):

> On March 28, 2010, the following changes were introduced, which, in particular, led to abolition of two of the eleven time zones.

```
* The Udmurt Republic and Samara Oblast started using Moscow Time, thus eliminating Samara Time.[2][3]
* Kemerovo Oblast started using Omsk Time.[4]
* Chukotka Autonomous Okrug and Kamchatka Krai started using Magadan Time, thus eliminating Kamchatka Time.[5]
```

There is no mention of daylight savings being canceled, only that its abolition was proposed.

Comment: Thank you. I maintain stuff that adjust content based on the user's local time, which is  based on geolocation. Not an exact science, but I do need to make adjustments :)

Answer (score 7):

According to [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia),

> On February 8th 2011, Russian
>   President Dmitry Medvedev issued a
>   decree cancelling DST in Russia. Under
>   the decree, all clocks in Russia will
>   advance one hour on March 27th 2011
>   but will not change back the following
>   October, effectively making Moscow
>   Time UTC+4 permanently.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia)